# What value of "wa" from the top command is too high?

Tags: linux, debian, io, top

I have a server with 64 GB of ram, 16 CPU cores and an SSD drive. I am running a relational database on the machine.

I would like to increase the writes to the database, and my guess would be that the SSD would be the bottle neck in my scenario. I am monitoring the "wa" value from the `top` command. Below is a screenshot of the server's top command

[image]

I have seen the "wa" value fluctuate from 0 to about 10%. What would value would indicate that the SSD is being pushed to its max write potential and I would stop increasing the writes to the server?

Answer (score 1):

`iowait` is the amount of time the CPU is waiting for storage tasks to complete.  There's no standard amount of wait that would be good, its dependent upon your app.

Try [`iostat`](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jump?q=iostat) for more information.